# adding a value in to the http request from a long to char

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to to add value in to the http request and getting errors when I add a long into the path.

```
   long test1, test2;
   unsigned long age;

   numdata=inet.httpGET("test.com", 80, '/system/get.php?value1='+test1+'&value2='+test2, msg, 50);
```

***error:*** invalid conversion from 'long int' to 'const char*'

And I have tried the following and getting an error.

```
const char getRequest = '/system/get.php?value1='+test1+'&value2='+test2;
numdata=inet.httpGET("test.com", 80, getRequest, msg, 50);
```

And am getting the following error

***error:*** invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Answer (score 1):

If would be better to use a `ostringstream` for this

```
#include <sstream>
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << "/system/get.php?value1=" << test1 << "&value2=" << test2;
```

then you can get at the `std::string` from the string stream using

```
ss.str();
```

Whatever you choose you should use `"` instead of single quotes when dealing with a `char` array. Use only single quotes when dealing with a single `char` variable.

What you are currently doing here

```
const char getRequest = '/system/get.php?value1='+test1+'&value2='+test2;
```

is declaring a `const char` - that is a single constant character. This is not the same as an array of `char`.